# css img inset box-shadow trick + center (v+h) anchor + max-height

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply the trick I found [here](https://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-inset-shadow-to-image-css3/) to add an inset box-shadow on the pictures of my gallery, however, I heve 3 problems:

1. I then can't center the image and surrounding anchor vertically and horizontally in their container
2. I can't restraint image height so it stays in said container like I can vertically with max-width
3. The shadow overflows a bit on the bottom of the image

Here is my gallery as it is now, working good but without box-shadow: https://jsfiddle.net/GaetanL/vLrt7o1m/17/

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="picture-frame">
    <img src="https://static.passeportsante.net/i93408-.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="picture-frame">
    <img src="https://www.wimadame.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/La-nature-me-parle.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.picture-frame {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 36px 36px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.picture-frame img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; /* for chrome & firefox */
  object-fit: contain; /* for edge */
  margin: auto;
}
```

And here is where I got so far, showing all the problems above: https://jsfiddle.net/GaetanL/07wmxe6a/24/

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="picture-frame">
    <a class="img-shadow">
      <img class="img-image" src="https://static.passeportsante.net/i93408-.jpeg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="picture-frame">
    <a class="img-shadow">
      <img class="img-image" src="https://www.wimadame.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/La-nature-me-parle.jpeg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.picture-frame {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 36px 36px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.img-shadow {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.img-shadow::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.img-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I found the answer, I needed to specify a max-height in absolute value, not %. Here is the final version: https://jsfiddle.net/GaetanL/07wmxe6a/37/

```
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.picture-frame {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 36px 36px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.img-shadow {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-shadow::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.img-image {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```